# How to track email open when the email content is encrypted

Tags: php, laravel, email, encryption, tracking

I am trying to track number of emails opened in a campaign in created.
I am aware of adding a tracking pixel in the emails.
i.e.

> https://test.com/track_email/update_read_flag?log=1

But the difficulty i am facing is the encrypted img src in emails
i.e.

> https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/RTzHKu_9loNFkhnUZu5bA2s0h1avJdhk7ZyUNGHjym5MsmigllT_9-Jara7EJoH_o2pM2Di83RRnG0pFM85YFvm4UYkPxI9dJdtPTGeSk8ggoSA8d5EuuqXmsNMrUuQBUTlFhw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://test.com/track_email/update_read_flag?log=1

This resulting in not updating the records.
Any sort of help will be highly appreciated

Comment: encrypted image source, what?

Comment: @lagbox I think he is refering to base_64...

Comment: we need more code

Comment: both the link are 404. the email is usually encripted with base64 encription. so you can decript with base64 decription.

Comment: @Abhinav Base64 is not an encryption, it is an encoding.  The difference is important...

Comment: sorry shakthiman..

Comment: @lagbox @Abhinav
I'm using TLS protocol for privacy. Not sure it's bcz of TLS or not. Used email tracking many times but it's not working this time. 
`mailed-by: amazonses.com
security:  Standard encryption (TLS)`
No problem in the code, i've tested the link, it's updating the read flag. Problem is in receiving email's img src.
It shld b like this in email:
`<img src="https://test.com/track_email/update_read_flag?log=1">`
But it's like:
`<img src ="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/RTzHKu_9loNFkhnUZu5bA2s_9-SUTlFhw=s0-d-e1-ft#https://test.com/track_email/update_read_flag?log=1">`